# "Rebind" a slider after calling .unbind()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I unbind a slider to disable people from moving it up and down after the game has ended, however when they click to play again, the slider should be re-bound to work again.

Inside my startGame() function which is what is called after init() but is also called on gameReset():

```
$( "#mySlider" )
.on('mousedown', sliderMouseDown)
.on('touchstart', sliderMouseDown)
.slider({
  orientation: "vertical",
  range: "min",
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  value: 0,
  step: 1,
  animate: "slow",
  slide: refreshSwatch,
  change: refreshSwatch
});
```

That code works perfectly fine for 'setting up' the slider initially but when gameReset() calls the startGame() code again, it doesn't seem to "re-bind" the sliders. I don't think I'm doing it correctly, is there another way?

The code I use to unbind on gameEnded() is:

```
$("#mySlider").unbind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of unbind try [destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-destroy)

```
$("#mySlider").slider( "destroy" );
```

Or you can [disable](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-disable) and [enable](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-enable) the slider

In `gameEnded()`

```
$( "#mySlider" ).slider( "disable" );
```

And in `gameReset()`

```
$( "#mySlider" ).slider( "enable" );
```